# Learning finite automata from symbol set and given sample

Tags: algorithms, formal-languages, automata, machine-learning

Good day. We have a finite automaton `F1`, for example,
[image]
.

We need to get automaton `F2` that accepts strings like accepted by `F1`, but symbols may be in different order. Clearly, there may be large number of combinations, factorials will be here. And we have a sample, for example,

`abcde`, `bacde`, `baced`.

As you can see, it is not random strings, there is some structure. How to learn `F2` from given sample? There are existing techniques and algorithms for that specific case (not common grammar and automata learning algorithms without additional information)? What is the automaton should be in my example and what will it be if we add

`abced`

to sample?

Answer (score 0):

There is a standard way to do this, though it is unlikely to give you the most efficient result.

First create a **non-deterministic** finite automaton to recognise the finite language you want.  This could consist of one "piece" like the one you have shown for each word - so, for your first question, three pieces: the states in the second would be labelled $b,a,c,d,e$ and in the third $b,a,c,e,d$.  All of the "left hand ends" would be initial states.  Then there is a standard algorithm for converting the NDFA to a DFA.  It begins by taking each state of the DFA to be a *set of states* from the NDFA.  The rest should not be hard to find online.

Comment: It sounds good in common, but when going into detail there are problems. And how to provide lifelong learning? I mean, sample will be added to the examples, the learning process should never stop.